# RVM do not recognize system's ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am running ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) on my fedora 13 machine. Now i want to try out ruby 1.9.2 so I installed RVM (rvm 1.0.1 by Wayne E. Seguin).

I want RVM to know my system's ruby, but unfortunately when I run "rvm list" it doesn't list any rubies. How can I make rvm recognize hence switch between system's and rvm's rubies?

Thanks,
Wa'el

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{~} ∴ rvm list
rvm rubies <<< important
```

As it tells you , it only lists rvm rubies. Run `rvm system` to switch to system ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I installed rvm with from git as explained at http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/
but it can't locate the system ruby interpreter in /usr/bin/ruby

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies


$ rvm system
$ rvm install 1.9.2-head # this goes on for a while recursively forking
                         # processes trying to install ruby 1.8.7
```

The error message I see, one per process, is

> To proceed rvm requires a
>   1.8-compatible ruby is installed. We attempted to install 1.8.7
>   automatically but it failed.
>   Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.

This is not very nice because it can bog down the whole machine, but why can't it see the system ruby interpreter?